# How to localize the anchor tag text in jquery 1i8n

Tags: jquery, internationalization

```html
Click <a style="text-decoration: underline" href="www.google.com">Here</a> to go.
```

Inside the hyperlink href is `www.blablabla.com`. How can I localize the Hyperlink text?

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
Click <a style="text-decoration: underline" href="www.google.com"><span     data-i18n="yourLocatizationKey">Here</span></a> to go.
```

i think its works.if you want to localize entire text try below code as well.

```
 <span data-i18n="yourClickLocatizationKey">Click</span> <a style="text-decoration: underline" href="www.google.com"><span data-i18n="yourLocatizationKey">Here</span></a> <span data-i18n="yourTogoLocatizationKey">to go</span>.
```

Comment: Hopefully it doesn't work. The reason is, in other languages like french or Spanish or in some languages, the text will change with respect to anchor tag. For an example what if text like "to go here click".